# Using textbox.text as string?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having this issue with my code, giving me errors.
Here's my code:

```
public void SetConnectionSettings(string ndisplayname, string nserverip, string nserverport)
    {
        string sdisplayname = ndisplayname;
        string sserverip = nserverip;
        string sserverport = nserverport;

    }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


         try
            {

                SetConnectionSettings(DisplayName.text, CBsip.text, CBsport.text);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException nre)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                   "Failed\n" +
                   nre.Message);
            }}
```

It tells me that

> It does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method
>   'text' accepting a first argument

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not using Intellisense or any other autocompletion?

Answer (score 2):

```
SetConnectionSettings(DisplayName.Text, CBsip.Text, CBsport.Text);
```

It's case sensitive, so you have to use upper case T

Answer (score 0):

In C#, methods, namespaces, classes and public fields use upper case.
Only local variables and private members use lower case.

So, when you want to access to a field or a method of a class, remember to use upper-case characters.